# How to change the custom release name format in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-extensions

I'm trying to change the release name format like V.1.0.0 in Azure DevOps release pipeline by following [Version number counter for Azure DevOps](https://msftplayground.com/2018/11/version-number-counter-for-azure-devops/) documentation. But the version number counter task is giving the following error:

> ##[error]The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

`Note: The same task I have used in Build pipeline there it is working as expected.`

So, please suggest me how to solve this problem.

Comment: can you share your task configuration?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk, I have configured the above task by following this https://msftplayground.com/2018/11/version-number-counter-for-azure-devops/ documentation